# Java Compiler issue

Tags: java, eclipse

I am facing this issue in my eclipse when I imported a project at one of the class. I have imported the same project in one of my colleague's Eclipse and it worked fine.

Following are the screenshots of error & Preferences Screenshot.

Please help me

> Internal compiler error: java.lang.ClassFormatError:
>   org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/ast/TypeReference$AnnotationPosition
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.resolveTypesFor(SourceTypeBinding.java:1874)

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This usually happens when you're running code compiled with a newer version of javac on a JVM with an older version. Check what JVM version you're running, and check which eclipse version you're running. Normally a java.lang.ClassFormatError also has information about the class file format version (or another detail message) - are you sure you have copied the entire error?

Comment: With Eclipse Oxygen (and most likely other version but can't remember), you have a warning when you open a workspace created from an older version telling you it will updates some configurations and this can't be reverted. Check the version of both Eclipse.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt  It is availabel now

Comment: @AxelH You can see my version now. The same version is being used in my colleagues Eclipse & it is working fine on his eclipse

Comment: Thank you all for your time. Below answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your .metadata  is probably corrupted.
try a new installation of eclipse, or follow [this](https://blog.pdark.de/2011/09/02/restoring-a-corrupted-workspace-in-eclipse/) to restore a corrupt workspace

Comment: Thanks man !!!! It worked like a charm !! I had been struggling with it for past 3 weeks. Note: Don't revert back .plugins for this error. I believe issue was in .plugins folder. As soon as I reverted back .plugins I started getting same error again